# python - How to change socket from client to SSL?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I am doing a proxy server.

```
server = socket.socket()
server.bind (("0.0.0.0", 1)) 
server.listen(5)
current_socket,adress = server.accept()
data = current_socket.recv(1024)
```

From the server program, How to change the socket to the client to ssl when the client sends a https request?

Comment: How will you know "when the client sends an https request"?

Comment: The request will start with "Connect". Can you help me to solve the problem? If the promlem isn't clear, I can explain more clearly.